# Apache2 can't bind to any port, multiple apache servers starting?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, port, httpd

I have changed the apache2 (httpd) on CentOS 6.4  listen port to 80, 443, 25640 etc no ports seem to work

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                       [FAILED]
```

I can't seem to find out what is taking the port though

when I start httpd webmin shows http://puu.sh/5k8Dl.png and if I kill that httpd starts successfully however no hosted sites load and with

```
service httpd restart
```

I get the same port failed to bind. Could apache start in two different places when I start it as webmin shows it as /usr/sbin/httpd?

Comment: Did this problem start after you added the additional ports? That might indicate a SELinux permission problem. The shell command `getenforce` will tell you if SELinux is enabled.

Comment: Ulrich Schwarz SELinux is disabled, the problem accrued after a user decided to install ALL apache modules from webmin... I removed all modules and reinstalled apache and php with   yum reinstall httpd -y.

Comment: ulrich-schwarz forgot to mention I am using the root user.

Answer (score 0):

if you have selinux disabled, are you sure the ports are not already used, use netstat to verify

Comment: Found the problem, some user on my system installed ALL the apache modules from webmin, they were taking port 80 as well. I fixed this with     yum remove httpd   then yum install httpd;yum install php